# Filter ArrayList with data as treeview

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have a class Detail.java
with some properties id, security, description, items.
Items is a ArrayList of Detail

```
public class Detail {

    private int id;
    private boolean security;
    private String description;
    private List<Detail> items;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public boolean isSecurity() {
        return security;
    }
    public void setSecurity(boolean security) {
        this.security = security;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public List<Detail> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<Detail> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

and this ArrayList (treeview) with my data

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "security": true,
        "description": "description 1",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "security": true,
                "description": "description 11"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "security": false,
                "description": "description 12",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 121,
                        "security": true,
                        "description": "description 121"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 122,
                        "security": false,
                        "description": "description 122"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "security": true,
                "description": "description 13"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "security": false,
                "description": "description 14"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "security": true,
        "description": "description 2",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "security": true,
                "description": "description 21"
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "security": false,
                "description": "description 22"
            },
            {
                "id": 23,
                "security": true,
                "description": "description 23"
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "security": false,
                "description": "description 24"
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

I want to filter or create this ArrayList by filtering all the nodes where the security is true

What the best way ? use iterator ? create a new arrayList with the first
and clone object ?
How manage items ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can create own method to recursively iterate over tree and remove non matching elements using `items.remove`

Comment: no I think because  I browse my arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Recently saw this question, so I gave it try. This recursive solution seems to work for me:

```
public class Main {

// ArrayList to popluate with elements
private static List<Detail> myDetails2 = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Detail> myDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    // Building up some sample data
    Detail detail = new Detail();
    detail.setId(1);
    detail.setSecurity(true);
    detail.setItems(Collections.emptyList());

    Detail detail5 = new Detail();
    detail5.setId(6);
    detail5.setSecurity(true);
    detail5.setItems(Collections.emptyList());

    Detail detail4 = new Detail();
    detail4.setId(5);
    detail4.setSecurity(true);
    detail4.setItems(Arrays.asList(detail5));

    Detail detail3 = new Detail();
    detail3.setId(4);
    detail3.setSecurity(true);
    detail3.setItems(Arrays.asList(detail4));

    Detail detail2 = new Detail();
    detail2.setId(3);
    detail2.setSecurity(true);
    detail2.setItems(Arrays.asList(detail3));

    Detail detail1 = new Detail();
    detail1.setId(2);
    detail1.setSecurity(false);
    detail1.setItems(Arrays.asList(detail2));

    myDetails.add(detail);
    myDetails.add(detail1);

    constructDetailsListWithSecurity(myDetails);
    // Printing out the id of the elements that were added to the filtered ArrayList
    myDetails2.forEach(d -> System.out.println("id: " + d.getId()));
}

public static void constructDetailsListWithSecurity(List<Detail> myDetails) {

    if (myDetails.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (Detail detail : myDetails) {
        if (detail.isSecurity()) {
            myDetails2.add(detail);
        }
        if (detail.getItems() != null && !detail.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            List<Detail> items = detail.getItems();
            constructDetailsListWithSecurity(items);
        }
    }   
}
```

}

I'm basically populating an ArrayList with only the elements where the security is set to true (I hope that I got you right with this, otherwise we would need to change the logic a bit). For this solution, the depth does not matter. This means that it could still handle cases where a Detail object has a list of Details, which again has a list of Details and so on.